# What would be a good Spanish translation for "label"?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, jerga-internet

In the context of the web (e.g. Instagram, etc.) what would be an appropriate translation for `label` in Spanish?

Would `etiqueta` be appropriate?
How about `tag`?

Comment: Welcome to [Spanish.SE]! Given that you mention Instagram, in that social network and some others, if you mean the tags beginning with '#', at least in Spain we have adopted the term "hashtag". If you refer to any other tag, could you please add more details to the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See, the problem is that *"In the context of the web"* can mean different things for different people.

- To you, per your Instagram etc. example, it seems to mean "for website users".
- To me, as a programmer, it usually means "for web developers".

In web and UI development, `label` and `tag` have distinct meanings:

- `label` is any piece of text that identifies (shows the name of) a form field or a similar web page element. The text "**Your Answer**" over the "new answer" text box, for example, is a `label`.
- `tag` is a word that identifies a specific category to which a given entity belongs. The words ***traducción***, ***vocabulario*** below your question are the `tags` that identify the categories into which your question falls.

The use of `label` predates the use of `tag` by several years, and I think that the latter entered into use precisely to avoid using `label` to name the categories too (it'd be kind of confusing then).

For a web user, though, there's no need to make such a distinction because they don't need to know what a (web development's) `label` is, so users can (and do) use `tag` and `label` interchangeably, since they're kind of synonyms everywhere else.

#### Now, how should they be translated to Spanish?

Well... [`tag` is not a Spanish word according to the DLE](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=tag). However, that doesn't mean you can't use it. The following is what I recommend:

- If you're a web developer or are translating a text related to that field, use **etiqueta** (regular font) for labels, and ***tag*** (italics, because it is a foreing word) for tags -- viceversa if the whole text was already in italics.
- If you don't need to make a distinction between `label` and `tag`, use ***etiqueta*** for both. Context should tell which is which if necessary.

There are other words, like ***pegatina*** (sticker) which could arguably be used for `tag` in certain contexts, but in most cases it would be weird.

Comment: Also when a distinction needs making, *tag* could also go as simply *categoría* or even *grupo*

Comment: Normally in HTML the `label` element doesn't traslate and `tag` term translate as `etiqueta`.

Comment: @walen: I was trying to be a bit vague with the context not to limit possibilities overly restrictively. Your differentiation of possibilities helps a lot!

Answer (score 2):

`label` in Spanish is used for something physical, while `tag` is more abstract.

`label` means `etiqueta`: that is a sticker or the paper used to show the price of a pair of jeans in a shop (physical). `etiqueta` can also be used to put something or someone into a group (like a rock band, or a pop band... that's `una etiqueta` as well), but that's also known as a `tag` (abstract).

So answering your question, `etiqueta` is appropriate, but using it as a `tag` and not as a `label`.